# Python, add trailing slash to directory string, os independently

Tags: python, string

How can I add a trailing slash (`/` for *nix, `\` for win32) to a directory string, if the tailing slash is not already there? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: You should use the `os.path` module (http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) instead of manipulating strings directly. Use `os.path.join` to concatenate path components.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker, so I can be sure there is a slash when I concat the folder string with a filename

Comment: thanks Tim for reminding, after reading the doc, I think the answer to my _real_ question is  os.path.join(folder, filename) and I don't have to worry about the slash at all. man, I am going to love python ;-)

Comment: That's why I asked - don't do this yourself, use `os.path.join` and let the standard library figure out the correct path separator.

Comment: -1: A bad question.  The real question is "how do I concatenate file names?"

Comment: @S.Lott I won't consider this 'bad'. the question is a valid question by itself. it's only a part of a bigger (one may say real) question.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, however, the question may still be of interest. For example, if you're using Python to supply input to another program, you might have a case where an argument needs a slash-ended path. That may be out of your control; and is a perfectly valid use case for Marco's answer below.

Comment: I think the question is good as it stands. I got here trying to work out how to put a '/' on the end of a statement containing `os.path.abspath`, which strips the slash. In summary: `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, ''))` doesn't have a trailing slash whereas `os.path.join(os.path.abspath(folder), '')` does.

Comment: This is a valid question because the recognised way to identify a single-level directory `foo/` rather than file `foo` is to use a trailing /. Therefore there are cases when you want to build a multi-directory path with `os.path.join` but ensure that the result ends in a / to maintain the convention. Otherwise there's no way to disambiguate a path `foo` (is that a directory or a filename? `os.path.dirname` will tell you its a file, but you might be using it as a directory name) unless the filesystem already exists (and that's not a given).

Answer (score 241, accepted):

`os.path.join(path, '')` will add the trailing slash if it's not already there.

You can do `os.path.join(path, '', '')` or `os.path.join(path_with_a_trailing_slash, '')` and you will still only get one trailing slash.

Comment: Also adds a slash when `path` happens to be a file rather than a directory. That's slightly inconvenient.

Comment: There seems to be an exception: `print(os.path.join(r'\\server\c',''))` gives `\\server\c` (whereas `print(os.path.join(r'\\server\c\x',''))` gives `\\server\c\x\ `)

Answer (score 35):

Since you want to connect a directory and a filename, use

```
os.path.join(directory, filename)
```

If you want to get rid of `.\..\..\blah\` paths, use

```
os.path.join(os.path.normpath(directory), filename)
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do it manually by:

```
path = ...

import os
if not path.endswith(os.path.sep):
    path += os.path.sep
```

However, it is usually much cleaner to use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Comment: Actually, checking `os.path.sep` is not the best approach here, since on windows the path can end both in `/` as well as `\ `.

Answer (score -2):

You could use something like this:

```
os.path.normcase(path)
    Normalize the case of a pathname. On Unix and Mac OS X, this returns the path unchanged; on case-insensitive filesystems, it converts the path to lowercase. On Windows, it also converts forward slashes to backward slashes.
```

Else you could look for something else on [this](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) page