# extract the file path from text

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which contains various types of paths and directories as well as some URLs. I am trying to get different paths excluding URLs and Windows directories (c:/).

```
txt = r'''
\Files\System\ado\

C:\Dir\me\match1\poq!"&\file.txt

http://example/uploads/ssh/

{drive of encrypted files}\FreezedByWizard.README.TXT

%Program Files%\Common Files\System\ado\

/home/user/web/other.longextension
'''
```

**The correct output:**

```
\Files\System\ado\

{drive of encrypted files}\

%Program Files%\Common Files\System\ado\

/home/user/web/
```

I have tried various regexes including these ones but I could not get the correct results.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:/[^/]+)*',re.I)
# pattern = re.compile(r'\b(\\.+\\|\/.+\/|\%.+\%)(?:[^\/]|\\\/)+?\b',re.I) 
# this one for example prints all subdirectories not the main one!

matches = re.findall(pattern,txt)
print(matches)
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but the site [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) may be helpful for figuring out why yours aren't working, as you can input test cases and see the effect of your regular expressions in realtime.

Comment: How do you distinguish Registry keys from file names? I doubt the part `?:` should be allowed multiple times. Also you need to allow backslash in addition to `/`, otherwise it won't match `C:\\`

Comment: I fixed the registry issue, I just need to get rid of lines (phrases) that are windows type directories or URLs.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is a helpful link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed that the lines you want either start with `\ { % or /`. Maybe something as simple as this will work for you?

```
^(?:\\|\{|\%|\/).+(?:\\|/)
```

[image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n1Iuov/3)

```
^                start at line start
(?:\\|\{|\%|\/)  non-matching group with different string starts
.+               match any character
(?:\\|/)         match until reaches \ or /
```

[Online Code Editor](https://onlinegdb.com/BkwGfidNB)

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:\\|\{|\%|\/).+(?:\\|/)', re.M)
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting for any inexperienced regex users reading this answer: be sure to include `re.M` (the [multi-line flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M)) as input argument in the `re.compile()` function.

Comment: Thanks, this is absolutely great! But what if there is no consistency in spacing between lines?  let say if they are like:
%Program Files%\Common Files\System\ado\
/home/user/web/ then we will get "%Program Files%\Common Files\Systemdo/home/user/web/"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I've fully understood your intentions about what exactly you're looking to capture, but the code below should produce your desired output for the examples that you gave.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:^\\.+\\)|(?:^%.+%\\.+\\)|(?:^{.+}\\(?:.+\\)?)|(?:^/.+/)', re.I | re.M)
matches = re.findall(pattern, txt)
print(*matches, sep='\n')
```

prints as output:

```
\Files\System\ado\
{drive of encrypted files}\
%Program Files%\Common Files\System\ado\
/home/user/web/
```

Clarification of the used regex pattern can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/46A7K8/1).

Answer (score 2):

Since [readability counts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) I'd suggest to *not* write your own regular expression but use [os.path.dirname](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) and [urllib.parse.urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html). The latter matches both URLs and filepaths starting with `C:\`

```py
from os.path import dirname, join
from urllib.parse import urlparse

txt = r'''
\Files\System\ado\
C:\Dir\me\match1\poq!"&\file.txt
http://example/uploads/ssh/
{drive of encrypted files}\FreezedByWizard.README.TXT
%Program Files%\Common Files\System\ado\
/home/user/web/other.longextension
'''

result = [dirname(line) for line in txt.split("\n") if not urlparse(line).scheme]
```

The result is:

```
\Files\System\ado
{drive of encrypted files}
%Program Files%\Common Files\System\ado
/home/user/web
```

If the trailing (back)slashes are required you can [easily add them by using os.path.join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736144/python-add-trailing-slash-to-directory-string-os-independently).

```py
result = [join(dirname(line), '') for line in txt.split("\n") if not urlparse(line).scheme]
```

Now `result` contains the following entries:

```
\Files\System\ado\
{drive of encrypted files}\
%Program Files%\Common Files\System\ado\
/home/user/web\
```